# Black screen and cursor booting Ubuntu 20.04 on Dell XPS

Tags: ubuntu, boot, drivers, nvidia

I have just bought a Dell XPS 15 9500 laptop. It came with Windows and I am trying to put Ubuntu 20.04 onto it.

I did the installation and removed Windows during the process. Everything seems to work fine and I get to the Ubuntu desktop.

During the installation I was told that I had to turn off RST in the BIOS and switch to ACHI, which I did:

[image]

After that everything seemed to install fine and Ubuntu was up and running. When I reboot however, the Dell logo appears but then it just goes to a black screen with a flashing cursor at the top left. It stays that way forever.

I have found this post that sounds like a similar issue:

https://superuser.com/questions/1498258/ubuntu-19-10-upgrade-has-destroyed-my-laptop-is-there-any-way-to-recover

A couple of additional pictures show that Ubuntu is set to be my primary (and only) boot device:

[image]

And I have secure boot mode switched on:

[image]

The final thing to say is that while I have been changing settings I have *occasionally* got Ubuntu to boot up, but I don't think it is reliably reproducible; once I reboot I get the same problem.

I also just saw a couple of posts (e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305862/after-an-update-and-reboot-in-ubuntu-20-04-i-can-no-longer-complete-the-boot) about this being a problem with nvidia 340. I tried what the second answer said (to remove the proprietary GPU drivers (from nvidia) and replace them by the generic driver), but that didn't seem to fix anything.

Is this a problem with the version of Ubuntu? Should I go down and try Ubuntu 18.04?

---

EDIT: When I enter Ubuntu recovery mode but then just select "resume boot" it then seems to manage to boot Ubuntu.

Comment: Turn off the Secure boot first.

Comment: I did try that before and it didn't seem to help. But that was before I tried to remove the propriety drivers. I will try it again.

Comment: Okay I have turned secure boot off. The same issue occurs currently.

Comment: Is this a dual boot system? Can you simply run the Live CD and see if the system boots normally?